# Calculate the complete solution of the differential equation: $y'+(2x-1)y=xe^x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Calculate the complete solution of the differential equation:
>   $y'+(2x-1)y=xe^x$

There is a problem with my solution because I cannot seperate the two variables $x,y$..

$y'+(2x-1)y = x \cdot e^x \text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{ |} -(2x-1)y$

$y'=x\cdot e^x-(2x-1)y$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = x \cdot e^x-(2x-1)y \text{ }\text{  }\text{ |} \cdot dx$

$dy= (x \cdot e^x - (2x-1)y)dx \text{ }\text{  }\text{ |} \int $

$\int dy = \int(x \cdot e^x -(2x-1)y)dx$

$c_1 = e^x(x-1) - (x^2-x)y + c_2$

Now forming this to $y$ is pointless because there will be other $y's$ when I divide :(

How could it be done correctly?

Comment: It is a first order linear ODE, so use an integrating factor. Multiply the equation by $\mu = e^{\int (2x-1)dx} $ and note that the equation can be written as $\frac{d}{dx}(y \mu) = \mu xe^x $

Comment: @infinitylord Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't usually integrate something that has both $x$ and $y$ terms in it.

You have a linear differential equation:

$y' + P(x) y = G(x)$

Multiply through by an integrating factor: $e^{\int P(x) dx}$

$e^{\int P(x) dx}y' + e^{\int P(x) dx}P(x) y = e^{\int P(x) dx}G(x)$

Now on the left hand side you do have one of those cases where you can integrate intermingled $x's$ and $y's$ as $\frac {d}{dx} e^{\int P(x) dx} y = e^{\int P(x) dx}y' + e^{\int P(x) dx}P(x) y$ which happens to be the LHS above.

The right hand side will be a function of $x.$

Comment: I'm glad you edited your answer to include the information from infinitylord's comment above.  (yeah, you added that comment within 5 minutes of posting your answer, so the edit history won't show it.  But your original answer wasn't an answer, but with the help of @infinitylord's comment, you ended with a better post.  Credit is due where credit belongs.

Comment: Just tacking this on for extra help. The end result is of the form $y(x) = \mu(x)^{-1}\int \mu(x)G(x)dx $. **common mistakes:** You cannot bring the $\mu(x)^{-1} $ into the integral, and remember the integral is indefinite, so you will have a factor of $C \mu(x)^{-1} $ added on at the end for some $C \in \mathbb{R} $ .

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

First solve the associated homogeneous ODE :
$$Y'+(2x-1)Y=0$$
This is a separable ODE. $\quad\to\quad Y=c\:e^{x-x^2}$

Then, change of function : $\quad y(x)=u(x)e^{x-x^2}$

Putting it into $y'+(2x-1)y=xe^x$ leads to a separable ODE which unknown function $u(x)$ is easy to find. I suppose that you can do it.

This is the so called "method of variation of parameter".